# merged deleted partition recovery

Tags: partition-recovery

I deleted one of my partition and merged it to the other partition. I forgot that I have an important file on the deleted partition. Is there any way to recover the files even though the said deleted partition is already merged on the other partition? Thank you.

Comment: Your file is unfortunately gone.

Comment: Even if I recover the files using a file recovery tool on the current drive?

Comment: I assumed you had already tried file recovery software

Comment: Try `photorec` then, or maybe `testdisk`. And in the future always backup data before changing partitions